# do I need to change terminal at mumbai airport?

Tags: air-travel, india, bom

I am traveling through Indigo from Oman to Mumbai to Bagdograh(Siliguri).I heard that I've to change airport in order to change terminal from 1 to 2. How long does it takes? The next flight to Bagdogra is after 4.5hrs of arrival, is it enough for me to reach and do the immigration?

Comment: "I heard that I've to change terminals." You change terminals only if Mumbai-Bagdogra flight is operated by a low cost carrier (like Indigo). Vistara and Air India fly out of T2 only.

Comment: thnx.appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From the [airport's website](https://www.mumbaiairport.com/terminals.php):

> - The 2 terminals are in fact two separate airports 5km one from other
> - If you have a flight connection landing in T2 and departing from T1, take in mind that the transfer process will take 2-3 hours
> - Domestic Terminal is busiest during the day while International Terminal is busiest during night
> - Is not allowed to check in more than 4 hours prior your flight

So if you have 4,5 hours between the flights, that should be enough time to transfer.

> There is a paid service that connects both terminals (Domestic -
>   Terminal 1B and International - Terminal 2).
>
> - T1B to T2: Prices Rs.245 for a Sedan. Rs.700 for a SUV.
> - T2 to T1B: Prices Rs.230 for a Sedan. Rs.750 for a SUV.
>
> The counters to buy the ticket are located:
>   T1B: Arrivals. Phone: 8767350021
>   T2: Level 2, International Arrivals. Phone: (022) 65882672